# access datasource record's data in client side script

Tags: google-app-maker

What am I trying to do is, I have couple of datasource and I need to use the records details for reporting purposing. I need to get each field's Start_date and extract the month from it and if it is current month, last month or ... I will count them, however, I tried everything to access my datasource, unfortunately, no luck at all. the result will be populated on another page.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access Data source in client script you can use the following code,

```
var record = app.datasources.DataSourceName.item.FieldName;
```

You can iterate loop as well if you have more than one record.

```
app.datasources.DataSourceName.items.forEach()
```